# Spliting MySql value with default function in mysql?

Tags: mysql, split

**I Have a sitatation like the following:**

In MySql Table Entries:

```
img_id name 

1      aa.jpg             
2      aab.mpeg             
3      aabc.jpg             
4      aabd.jpg             
5      aabn.jpg             
6      aabf.jpg             
7      aadf.jpg             
8      aacf.jpg
```

I want the count after splitting thew above values........

like

```
".jpg"=>7
".mpeg"=>1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT(Name, LOCATE('.', REVERSE(Name)) - 1) Format, 
       COUNT(*) TotalCOunt
FROM   TableName
GROUP  BY RIGHT(Name, LOCATE('.', REVERSE(Name)) - 1)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5dfa2/1)

Consider normalizing the table. In the long run, this will perform slow.